# How to calculate the area of several MultiPolygons from a geoJSON file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

I'm trying to calculate the area of each feature (i.e. neighbourhood) in a GeoJSON file.  Ideally, the result would be either added as a field in file or in a separate dataframe, however I'm unable to even calculate the area at present.  My code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import json
from area import area

bdry_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/xu6q-xcmj.geojson")
with bdry_url as bdry_file:
    bdry = json.load(bdry_file)


for x in bdry['features']:
    print(area(x))
```

The result from the code above is a lot of 0's.  The area function is supposed to ['calculate the area inside any GeoJSON geometry'](https://pypi.org/project/area/1.1.0/). So, I'm not sure if I'm just not passing the file correctly to the function or if the function doesn't like 'MultiPolygons' like those in the file.

When I use just `print(x)` in the `for` loop, the output is for example:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[-113.47970029870794, 53.6152271386194], [-113.47623664663439, 53.61561158319339], [-113.4744820422431, 53.6158162210957], [-113.4731808787134, 53.61590027235317], [-113.4674204545053, 53.61591375444001], [-113.46742798260262, 53.610538856185805], [-113.46743523571406, 53.60691755885339], [-113.46961818955656, 53.60690984975463], [-113.47022601929541, 53.60689581095175], [-113.47086485888067, 53.60685578200864], [-113.4715850828474, 53.606767279197136], [-113.47225008266139, 53.606645830070825], [-113.47373112695321, 53.6063652736457], [-113.47641979230873, 53.6058984811946], [-113.47672620998279, 53.60585027816153], [-113.47791436479508, 53.60576846613057], [-113.48101443948326, 53.605768565180774], [-113.48173969843924, 53.605811862524945], [-113.4824407929969, 53.605915397805376], [-113.48510468465751, 53.606306092276874], [-113.48850157059921, 53.60679389522115], [-113.488933001326, 53.606820031912164], [-113.49168085687263, 53.606784967555676], [-113.49170507787457, 53.60810574183392], [-113.49171395279058, 53.61275181411882], [-113.49179330220164, 53.614032553715944], [-113.48966991380574, 53.6140237367952], [-113.48906656552556, 53.61404155038072], [-113.48794288078807, 53.614190044322235], [-113.48600883911077, 53.61444001996334], [-113.47970029870794, 53.6152271386194]]]]}, 'properties': {'descriptio': 'Evansdale is named for H.M.E. Evans, Mayor of Edmonton in 1918. Mr. Evans was also president of the Edmonton Board of Trade in 1916. Although single detached homes account for 90% of the structures in Evansdale, almost 50% of the dwelling units are locat', 'descriptiv': 'Evansdale', 'name': 'EVANSDALE', 'neighbourh': '2260'}}
```

Comment: Did you mean `area(x)`? Otherwise you don’t use `x` at all.

Comment: Whoops. Thank you, I did mean `area(x)` and have edited the question to show that now.  It doesn't change anything though as I still wind up with a 399 0's.

Comment: Can you show an example of when you `print(x)` directly?

Comment: added `print(x)` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `area` library wants *only* the geometry, not the entire feature. So try this instead:

```
for x in bdry['features']:
    print(area(x['geometry']))
```